# Entering Value at Runtime Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am using Oracle and basically I have to write a query to list patients by location name entered at runtime.

This is the query i have so far:

```
SELECT person.Person_ID, person.First_Name, person.Surname, patient.DOB, location.Location_Name, location.Arrival_Date 
FROM ((person

INNER JOIN patient ON person.Person_ID= patient.Person_ID)


INNER JOIN location ON person.Location_ID=location.Location_ID
WHERE location.Location_Name=&Location_Name);
```

So far when I run the query it works but when I input location name I get an error. I get a error message saying invalid identifier

Comment: The exact error message would have helped... But try single quotes around each `&Location_Name`.

Comment: Thanks for replying I edited the question to make it simpler. The exact error message I get is: Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "WARD": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Is "WARD" the value you entered for a location name?

Comment: Thanks a lot adding the single quote worked. The value was actually 'Ward' not sure if oracle is case sensitive but its working now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @Nas , welcome to SO ! Please add as an answer with description , what changes made your problem solved..by this way it will be helpful for others in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I used the single quotation mark `location.Location_Name = '&Location_Name'` also I made sure I inputted values as it is stored because I found out oracle is case sensitive